# query running but not displaying anything

Tags: php, mysql

i have following code in my program. i don't add database connection and $cat_id those are all good.

```
<?php
$subCategoryResult = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM sub_category WHERE cat_id='".$cat_id."' ORDER BY id");
?>
<div class='col-lg-12'>
            <?php
                while($subCategoryRow = mysql_fetch_assoc($subCategoryResult)){
                    echo "<h3 class='cd-box cd-header'>asd".$SubCategoryRow[2]."</h3>";
                }
            ?>  
            </div>
```

now, this query display 7 h3 tags if 7 records in database but not displaying any thing for **$SubCategoryRow[2]**. it's displaying blank...any help?

Comment: Stop using `mysql_*` functions. They've been deprecated since the dawn of time!

Comment: how many cols your database structure have?

Comment: also capital "s" in `$subCategoryRow`. Typo?

Comment: Pls do some error handling and debugging and provide us with an error message or more detailed description of the unexpected behaviour!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Look for var names: $**s**ubCategoryRow and $**S**ubCategoryRow